# Whats is the difference between Quill Delta and Parchment

Tags: quill

I don't find a clear distinction between those two concepts. Parchment is said to be the document model but, from my understanding, Delta is the document model and Parchment is a way to transform this model to HTML.

Can someone clarify this ?

Thanks